# why does onStart() method run before onCreate in my android project?

Tags: java, android, oncreate, onstart

According to the activity lifecycle, onCreate() is called once when the app is created, followed by the onStart() method which may be called multiple times throughout the activity lifecycle. Yet that's not whats happening to me.

I have this code inside my onCreate method:

```
mRef.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onChildAdded(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String s) {


                Gig thisGig =  dataSnapshot.getValue(Gig.class);

                loadedGigs.add(thisGig);
                Log.w("onCreate", "There are " + loadedGigs.size() + "Gigs loaded in the array.");


                arrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }

            @Override
            public void onChildChanged(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String s) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onChildRemoved(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onChildMoved(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String s) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
```

And then I have my onStart method:

```
@Override
    protected void onStart()
    {
        super.onStart();
        Log.w("onStart", "There are " + loadedGigs.size() + "Gigs loaded in the array.");


    }
```

And here are the logs:

```
V/FA: onActivityCreated
W/onStart: There are 0Gigs loaded in the array.
V/FA: Activity resumed, time: 2460468116
D/FA: Logging event (FE): screen_view(_vs), Bundle[{ga_event_origin(_o)=auto, ga_previous_class(_pc)=search_gigs_activity, ga_previous_id(_pi)=-5229767692724064313, ga_screen_class(_sc)=search_gigs_results_activity, ga_screen_id(_si)=-5229767692724064312}]
D/NetworkSecurityConfig: No Network Security Config specified, using platform default
W/onCreate: There are 1Gigs loaded in the array.
W/onCreate: There are 2Gigs loaded in the array.
W/onCreate: There are 3Gigs loaded in the array.
V/FA: Inactivity, disconnecting from the service
```

I had other code but i deleted it all because I kept getting a null pointer exception and couldn't figure out why. Turns out I was trying to access the "loadedGigs" array list from inside the onStart method thinking it had already been populated from the onCreate method.

Any ideas on why this is happening? My best guess is it has something to do with my use of Firebase and the child event listener. I'm lacking quite a bit of knowledge and I think that's why I can't figure it out.

Thx in advance,
Vlad

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**FACT CHECK**

Fact of the matter is, `onCreate()` is called first then `onStart()` follows. But because you are making a firebase call to get your dataset, your `onStart()` is not waiting for this to complete, meaning your list inside `onStart` is still not populated. Remember when `onCreate` is called, whatever code is executed there, it does not pause `onStart` from being called. Likewise, `onStart` is not waiting for all the code inside `onCreate` to finish before exeuting it's own code.

**YOUR PROBLEM**

Seems you want to do something inside `onStart` after you get your dataset from firebase eventlisteners inside `onCreate`. I

**A SUGGESTION MAYBE?**

You can use `LiveData` to let your code inside `onStart` know that firebase event listeners are done, and have prepared the data you need to use in `onStart`.

**WHAT IS LIVEDATA YOU ASK?**

> LiveData is an observable data holder class. Unlike a regular
>   observable, LiveData is lifecycle-aware, meaning it respects the
>   lifecycle of other app components, such as activities, fragments, or
>   services. This awareness ensures LiveData only updates app component
>   observers that are in an active lifecycle state.

See more [here](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/livedata)

**HOW WILL IT LOOK LIKE:**

```js
//just add dependency into the app/build.gradle .
def lifecycle_version = "1.1.1"
implementation "android.arch.lifecycle:extensions:$lifecycle_version"
annotationProcessor "android.arch.lifecycle:compiler:$lifecycle_version"


// Create an instance of LiveData to hold your firebase dataset eg List of Gig object
private MutableLiveData<List<Gig>> myGigLiveData;

.......
//initialize inside onCreate()
myGigLiveData = new MutableLiveData<>();

.......

mRef.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onChildAdded(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String s) {

                Gig thisGig =  dataSnapshot.getValue(Gig.class);

                loadedGigs.add(thisGig);
                Log.w("onCreate", "There are " + loadedGigs.size() + "Gigs loaded in the array.");


                arrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                
                //set the dataset value to livedata
                myGigLiveData.setValue(loadedGigs);
            }
            ...............
            
            
            
            //observe the livedata in onStart like so:
            @Override
    protected void onStart()
    {
        super.onStart();
       
myGigLiveData.observe(this, gigsList ->{
Log.w("onStart", "There are " + gigsList.size() + "Gigs loaded in the array.");
});

    }
```

Comment: This is a very useful answer. Few things tho... What is gigsList that you're using when observing myGigLiveData? Also...what is observing? How do I further access this data that I'm observing? I would like to be able to access these loaded gigs by index (maybe?, there could be millions of gigs) and further access some data these objects are storing.

Comment: gigsList is the change observer. It can be any type of data type you need to observe. LiveData simply helps you subscribe to changes in your data from wherever it comes from. You can understand more about it here https://medium.com/@elye.project/understanding-live-data-made-simple-a820fcd7b4d0

Comment: I believe almost all the answers posted here have clarified what you asked. For questions on how to load more gigs, open a different question. Accept one of the answers so the question doesn't remain unanswered.

Answer (score 3):

In your activity onCreate() is called before onStart(), but in your onCreate() method you only add the childEventListener, while the event **onChildAdded** only occurs after onStart() is called, and that's what you see in the logs.

Comment: This is indeed what is happening.

Comment: Yup. You're right. Thx I understand how it works now.

Answer (score 2):

You start populating your `loadedGigs` list in `onChildAdded` callback that is (in your case) fired AFTER activity's `onStart()` invocation.

According to the documentation, `ChildEventListener`'s ["appropriate method will be triggered when changes occur"](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/ChildEventListener.html) which means it will happen at some moment in the future in async fashion, so you shouldn't expect your data exists in activity's `onStart()`.

One more thing. Your `Log.w("onCreate",...)` is not about activity's lifecycle `onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)`, and such log output message may confuse.

Comment: Very nice explanation. I hope the OP has understood this by now.

Comment: Yes I see now. Thx. And thx for pointing out the Log thing. You're totally right. Any suggestions on how I can load my database data in onCreate() and access it during onStart()?

Comment: I wouldn't recommend you to mix these two completely unrelated flows up. What you can best (from UX perspective) do is to subscribe on your Firebase ref updates in `onCreate` (like you're already doing now) and display some `ProgressBar` on your UI until the `ChildEventListener` callbacks eventually fired.